# iTerm 2 change row size using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, iterm2

I want to change the height of my terminal window using a script. Currently this is what I have come up with:

```
tell application "iTerm"
activate

    tell the current terminal       
        tell the current session
            set number of rows to 30
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

And I keep on getting this error:

```
Can't set number of rows of current session of current terminal to 30.
```

Furthermore, what I would like to do is, have a script that will simply increment the row size by 1. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I checked the AppleScript dictionary, and it turns out, number of rows is a property for a 'terminal', not a 'session', so I tried this code:

```
tell application "iTerm"
activate

    tell the current terminal
        set number of rows to 30
    end tell
end tell
```

And I am getting this error now:

```
iTerm got an error: Can't set current terminal to 30.
```

There isn't even a mention of the row size anymore. It is trying to set the 'terminal' to 30??

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. Similar examples are also posted on the [Google Code wiki](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/wiki/AppleScript) for iTerm2.

```
tell application "iTerm"
    tell the current terminal
        set number of rows to 30
    end tell
end tell
```

The error you're getting seems weird enough, but the syntax is correct. Try restarting AppleScript Editor and iTerm2. You could also try assigning a new terminal like `set newterm to (make new terminal)`, and then `tell newterm to set number of rows to 30` or similar.